# Create ASP.Net Handler to return Image as Bytes

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am looking at creating a handler to return images based on id passed through, I haven't created my own one before and when I created it it mentions that it has to be registered with IIS.  This project is distributed to a lot of clients, will I have to change each one's IIS or is there some way round this or an alternative to a handler?

EDIT: In response to below, this is what I have created (but not yet tested), so will I need to change anything in IIS or web.config for this?

```
public class Photos : IHttpHandler
{
    #region IHttpHandler Members

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        //write your handler implementation here.
        var img = Image.FromFile(@"C:\Projects\etc\logo.jpg");
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
        img.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: See edit, builds ok but not returning image despite checking path is correct.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a class that inherits `IHttpHandler` and within that grab the id (from the querystring or similar), process the request and return the binary data. Shouldn't have to register it with IIS...

```
public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        //Get Id from somewhere

        //Get binary data

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that looks fine to me!

Comment: Seconded, that is the way to solve this thing, and the `jpeg` return type is better than `octet-stream`, makes it more obvious to clients what they're getting.

Comment: Thanks, tested using <img src='Photos.ashx' /> but image is not displayed.  Is it possible I've missed something or does it have to be an asp image control?

Comment: @WillemDuncan yes! I believe his question prior to edit mentioned returning binary data which is why I set `octect-stream`...

Comment: @user1166905 what happens when you navigate to `http://localhost:{port}/Photos.ashx`?

Comment: @DaveZych Get  parser error, I had an asp.net handler to start and then created a generic one and renamed it but guess there is something still looking at it somewhere as get this:
    Line 1:  <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" CodeBehind="StudentPhotos.ashx.cs" Class="StudentPhotos1" %>
Notice the 1 at the end of class!

Comment: @DaveZych Did a search and found where to change it!

Answer (score 4):

You can add a **generic handler** to your project (a `.ashx` file). It will give you a file with a codebehind as follows (excerpt):

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
    context.Response.Write("Hello World");
}
```

You can use the `context` to get query string or route parameters, and the `context.Response` property to write your image. Change the returned content type to your image content type, and you're set.

You would set your image `src` to: `"Handler1.ashx?id=12345"`, or you could add a pretty url route pointing to the handler.

No need to configure IIS for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this blogpost about Handlers, http://www.dotnetperls.com/ashx, which I think is pretty close to what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

The httphandlers are registered in web.config of website, if you distribute the config file with website you don't need to change iis configuration