# With Chrome what format to use with image src attribute when file is located on network drive?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, google-chrome, ckeditor

So ive been through several posts and searches, but im still at a loss for how to get Chrome to display images when the src attribute uses a file thats located on another server.  Im getting the image and setting its path via a custom file browser that Im hooking into CKeditor with.  Works fine in IE, just not chrome.

This is for an intranet, and some of the image content is stored off of the web server.  Although IE displays fine, it seems that Chrome does not like to display images with the src attribute is of a format like

```
file://server_name/share_name/folder_1/file_1.png
```

Strange, even though Chrome will pass the users identity, so its not a security issue.  Also, if I take the path and directly paste it in the url window of Chrome, it displays fine.  Just not when a img src value.

If this was just a page on its own, I could use a custom handler and write to the response stream, but this needs to work with a content editor.

Id like to include Chrome since many of our users have it and use it daily, but our default is IE.

Are there any file url schemes, or Chrome settings that will override these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue may not be the image or URL format. I'd wager that it's browser security restrictions.

To ensure that maliciously designed web pages can't access a user's local files, accessing any data from the user's filesystem (especially network drives) is generally disallowed in most modern browsers. (At least in their default configuration. There may be policies or runtime parameters to override these for testing purposes such as Chrome's `--disable-web-security` parameter, but these are purposefully difficult to turn off.)

If you want the content to display across all browsers, you'll likely need to deliver it via HTTP(s) like the rest of the page content.

Comment: I think Im going to try building a handler as mentioned in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21460727/create-asp-net-handler-to-return-image-as-bytes